# bokeh plot graph horizontally

Tags: html, django, bokeh

I'm plotting graph as

```
script, div = components(p)

return render(request, 'index.html', {"the_script": script, "the_div": div})
```

And in index.html I have

```
<body>
    <div>
        {{the_script | safe}}

        {{the_div | safe}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I'm trying to plot 2 graphs horizontally I see option to use such as `components(p1, p2)` and I added another `div` tag underneath current one. But it plots graph vertically how can I plot them horizontally.

Comment: What if you put these in two separate `<div>`s?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options. Either use bokeh's layout, so you would have `components(row(p1, p2))`, where `row` is imported from `bokeh.layouts`. This has the advantage that axes can be lined up, among other things, if desired. Or, if you insist on doing this on HTML-level, you will need to write some CSS to make the plots positioned horizontally. You can use CSS' flexbox or grid layouts to achieve this, e.g. it can be as simple as adding `style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"` to the parent div (the one that contains `the_div`). However, quite a lot also depends on other factors, like other CSS, your particular plot setup (sizing modes involved) or bokeh's version, so there other changes may be needed.

Comment: not sure how `components(row(p1, p2))` suppose to work I tried `script, div = components({'p1':p1, 'p2':p2})` and updated body as `{{the_script | safe}}

        {{the_div.p1 | safe}}

        {{the_div.p2 | safe}}` It plots graph vertically but if I try `script, div = components(row({'p1':p1, 'p2':p2}))` I get error `ValueError: Only LayoutDOM items can be inserted into a row.`

Comment: what should be `body` for `components(row(p1, p2))`